# Is it a bad idea to start to write a microservices NodeJS backend application in REST, then try to convert/wrap some/whole parts with gRPC or GraphQL?

Tags: node.js, rest, graphql, microservices, grpc

Is it a wrong manner to start writing a NodeJS application using REST architecture, then try to use GraphQL or gRPC approaches in some parts or completely rewrite some or whole the application in the future?

The reason for doing this is previous experience and coding speed in REST APIs. But at the other hand it's kinda a big microservices project and should support millions of users.

Comment: Same post here: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/442341/is-it-a-bad-idea-to-start-to-write-a-microservices-nodejs-backend-application-in

Comment: @jfriend00: Here I am asking from developers, the other post asks from system engineers. I want to see both point of views.

Comment: I'm just making sure that people don't waste time on answers that already exist in the other place.  I don't have an opinion on posting the same question multiple places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GraphQL is not going to help you scale, quite the opposite in many cases. GraphQL is an optimization (in some cases) but mostly for developer productivity, but there is a complexity cost.

Generally I would suggest to steer away from this optimization unless you have a clear understanding of what you're solving for. REST is a good 'default choice' because it's well understood, requires little tooling and is pretty universal.

Once you are further into your project and you find that you have (ideally measurable) challenges, you're in a much better place to decide to use a more specialized paradigm (gRPC/graphql) and why, but it doesn't sound like you're there yet.

Comment: So it wouldn't be very expensive at that time to rewrite an active application with millions of users? No body will say "You should have spent more time to learn and chose the right architecture from the beginning to avoid facing this mess?".

Comment: Actually I am asking for a startup project that we guess it will have a very fast growing because of the idea and other reasons.

Comment: Also it's still a question to me, how many daily active user can an app written in NodeJS and REST architecture handle? For example if the Amazon mobile app was written in REST or Instagram app, how many users they could handle with that architecture?

Comment: @WDR You almost never need to rewrite the entire application. As you grow you will hit bottlenecks in specific features, and you might need to rewrite parts. But it's hard to predict which parts need this treatment, and you will get into this situations _regardless_ of what protocol you use.

Comment: In terms of using Node, Go, Python, Java, PHP, they are _all good enough_. People have preferences but if they argue that one is universally better than another they are lying or inexperienced. There's a pretty low correlation between tech stack and the success of a company.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your answers. But I still like to know if there is any benchmarking or estimation or experience to say "An application written in REST can't handle more than 10 millions of user"?  I guess maybe there was some problems with applications written in REST then they decided to move to GraphQL or gRPC? I like to know at what scale those problems start showing up?

Comment: @WDR - You're asking a question that has no answer because it depends upon exactly what your application is doing.  You could write a nodejs application that did so much database work on every single request that it only scaled to 10 simultaneous users, but the same underlying architecture that has only very lightweight things to do scales to 1,000,000 simultaneous users.  Then, cluster it and it supports more than that.  So, it depends entirely upon where your bottlenecks are, what they are doing and how you design them and NOT at all on what dev platform you choose.

Comment: @WDR - Plus, none of this is predetermined by your platform choice. As you scale you discover bottlenecks and you deploy solutions.  Sometimes those solutions involve "fixing" parts of your client or server code to be more efficient and sometimes they involve just scaling your server deployment horizontally to meet the needs. You might even take some CPU-heavy portion of your code and write it in C++ and put that in a microservice that your main server then uses. There are lots and lots of choices for "fixing" scaling issues and none of them involve rewriting in a different framework/language.

Comment: @jfriend00: Thanks a lot for your points. As this is a startup project and I am not a web development expert, but have some experience using NodeJS and Flutter, I just wanted to make sure if I start with my previous knowledge, it works and it is not a bad decision, because this thoughts always fly in my head that says "learn the latest technologies and use them from the beginning". So I will go with REST then after we reached a certain amount of users we can hire experts in gRPC/GraphQL or whatever, if it would be really necessary.

Comment: Most of these thought is because we think the application has a great idea and would have a very fast growing( atleast at the beginning) and I am afraid of it getting stuck very soon after launching and it can't handle many users. (Maybe it's just because this is my first experience and I am just overthinking).

Comment: @WDR - Your choice of REST nodejs is fine.  The bigger questions for scalability will be how you horizontally scale your system (first to multiple CPUs in a single host) and then to multiple hosts and how you scale whatever data store you're using. If it is a design requirement that you be able to scale quickly, then you should have a preliminary design for how this horizontal scaling would work both for server compute and for server data.  You will not implement that horizontal scaling at first, but you will implement the first version such that it's not a major rewrite to later implement it.

Comment: @WDR - How much of this large, horizontal scaling to plan for is an interesting tradeoff for a startup.  One of the most important rules in a web startup is to get your minimum, viable product to market fast so you can start learning what works and doesn't work and what customers like and don't like so you can iterate quickly and adapt to what you learn.  This generally means you don't implement high scale stuff initially.  But, you don't want to design yourself into a box either that requires massive rewrite to scale.  To do that balance well generally takes experience.

Comment: @jfriend00: Thanks again, so I will start with NodeJS, MySQL and Cassandra that I know a little and have some experience in, but at the same time I will also learn about horizontal scaling and try to get it into my architecture from the beginning. I think now I got a good idea about how should I proceed the work.

Comment: If you also know a good resource( specially video or article) about horizontal scaling and how to consider it while designing the architecture of the project, I will be so happy to have it!

Comment: @WDR I don't have a video, just keep it simple and follow https://12factor.net/ .